# Download Newest Windows 11x64 CUs for: System & .NET Framework with PowerShell or any other automation tool

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm trying to create automation script for download last offline versions of Windows Update CUs for Windows11 23H2 x64 (.msu installation files).

I created PowerShell code for that based on that page:
[How to download and install offline Windows updates with PowerShell](https://cherrypicking.dev/download-and-install-offline-windows-updates)
but I stuck somehow on last download step. This is my code for download:

```
Install-Module -Name "MSCatalog"
Update-Module -Name "MSCatalog"
$DestinationDir = "D:\WinUpd"


# CU Standard
$UpdCUStandardName      =   "Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems"

(Get-MSCatalogUpdate -Search $UpdCUStandardName) | Where { $_.Title -match $UpdCUStandardName } | Select -First 1 | FL

$UpdCUStandardGuid      =   ((Get-MSCatalogUpdate -Search $UpdCUStandardName) | Where { $_.Title -match $UpdCUStandardName } | Select -First 1 | Select-Object -Property "Guid").Guid
$UpdCUStandardTitle     =   ((Get-MSCatalogUpdate -Search $UpdCUStandardName) | Where { $_.Title -match $UpdCUStandardName } | Select -First 1 | Select-Object -Property "Title").Title

Write-Host "UpdCUStandardGuid is: $UpdCUStandardGuid"
Write-Host "UpdCUStandardTitle is: $UpdCUStandardTitle"


Save-MSCatalogUpdate -Guid $UpdCUStandardGuid -Destination $DestinationDir
```

And how its works and stuck is on bellow printscreen:
[image: Screen]

Even I putted there Guid to download (what I understand as unique name) script stuck and ask me:
"Multiple files exist for this update. Enter the Id of the file to download or 'A' to download all files.:"
When I press 'A', nothing is download and its basically quits. I already tried also write 0,1, Guid, but with no luck.

From Other hand, when I change
$UpdCUStandardName = "Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems"
to
$UpdCUStandardName = "Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5034127)"
its gonna work:
[image]

Did I done something wrong in my code, or CUs for Win11 is somehow blocked to download with PS command 'Save-MSCatalogUpdate'?
Or maybe there is another method (tool) to automatically after "path day" download all of them?